# VM Player Error

Tags: vmware-player

Error while opening the virtual machine: Taking ownership of this virtual machine failed.

The virtual machine is in use by an application on your host computer.

Configuration file: E:\Folder1\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmx.

Comment: When does this message show up? What happens when you dismiss it?

Comment: Have you checked that directory for .lck or .lock files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In Windows Explorer, navigate to the folder which houses your VM files
2. Delete the sub-folder named %VMNAME%.vmx.lck
3. Open up VMWare Workstation and power on the VM

Make a backup before you do this, just in case.